# How to solveTS6143: '--allowJs' is not set

Tags: angularjs, typescript, npm, cmd, angular-material

The Error is TS6143: Which gives the following error after I run npm start

```
src/main.ts
Module './radio-ng-model-example' was resolved to 'C:/Users/saish/Documents/my-app/quickstart/src/radio-ng-model-example.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.
```

- Typescript version is 2.2
- npm version 3.10.9
- node version 7.2.0
- angular cli version 1.0.0-rc.2

main.ts

```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  MdAutocompleteModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdButtonToggleModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdCheckboxModule,
  MdChipsModule,
  MdCoreModule,
  MdDatepickerModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdExpansionModule,
  MdGridListModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdListModule,
  MdMenuModule,
  MdNativeDateModule,
  MdPaginatorModule,
  MdProgressBarModule,
  MdProgressSpinnerModule,
  MdRadioModule,
  MdRippleModule,
  MdSelectModule,
  MdSidenavModule,
  MdSliderModule,
  MdSlideToggleModule,
  MdSnackBarModule,
  MdSortModule,
  MdTableModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdTooltipModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import {RadioOverviewExample} from './radio-overview-example';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    CdkTableModule,
    MdAutocompleteModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdButtonToggleModule,
    MdCardModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    MdChipsModule,
    MdCoreModule,
    MdDatepickerModule,
    MdDialogModule,
    MdExpansionModule,
    MdGridListModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdInputModule,
    MdListModule,
    MdMenuModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    MdPaginatorModule,
    MdProgressBarModule,
    MdProgressSpinnerModule,
    MdRadioModule,
    MdRippleModule,
    MdSelectModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    MdSliderModule,
    MdSlideToggleModule,
    MdSnackBarModule,
    MdSortModule,
    MdTableModule,
    MdTabsModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdTooltipModule,
  ]
})
export class PlunkerMaterialModule {}

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    PlunkerMaterialModule,
    MdNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],

  declarations: [RadioOverviewExample],
  bootstrap: [RadioOverviewExample],
  providers: []
})
export class PlunkerAppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(PlunkerAppModule);
```

Comment: And what does `npm start` do (what is the command aliased to "start" in `package.json`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renamed the file *radio-ng-model-example* to **radio-overview-example** and did `npm start`

Comment: Do you want to know why that worked?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Yeah sure